# CUDA MemcpyHostToDevice

Tags: cuda, memcpy, nvcc

```
typedef struct {    
        int M;  
        int N;  
        int records[NMAX][SZM];     
        int times[NMAX];    
        bool prime[NMAX]; 
} DATASET;

typedef int ITEMSET[SZM];

__device__ DATASET d_db;

DATASET db;

int main(void) {

    loadDB();       
    cudaMemcpy(&d_db, &db, sizeof(DATASET), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    ...
```

I have a device variable d_db a variable db on the host. After I load same value on my db variable, I want to copy this variable on device. Compiling there are no errors, but when I execute the code there are some wornings about cache and sometimes the pc is restarted. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Using `__device__` variables you need to use `MemcpyToSymbol` and `MemcpyFromSymbol` instead of `cudaMemcpy`.
So in my case I have to use

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_db,&db,sizeof(DATASET)));
```

Comment: You could also declare `DATASET *d_db;` and then allocate the memory with `cudaMalloc(&d_db, SZM * sizeof(DATASET));` (and don't forget to `cudaFree(d_db)` it when you're done with it).